# Wait image till the export to excel file is downloaded mvc3 jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to implement export to excel functionality on button click event. There are 50K records in table so it is taking time. I want to show wait spinning image till the file is downloaded. Right now , I am using Fileresult action method and the file is downloaded and it is working. I thought of implementing it in ajax and  and on success event hide the spinning image but my file is generated on the fly and moreover for ajax return type it needs to be json. Any suggestions or other approach?

Comment: show us what you have attempted so far

Comment: Post your ajax function if you can.  Generally what you'll do is display the wait right before the ajax call, then kill it in the "on complete" section.  Once we see your ajax we can probably clarify.